# Как создать ежедневный event, работающий в определённый промежуток времени?

Tags: mysql

Например, каждый день с 8 до 21 часа

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, как вы представляете себе **разовое** событие, происходящее «с 8 до 21 часа»? оно должно происходить один раз в «8 часов»? каждый час? каждую минуту?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, каждую минуту, например. но ночью тикать не должно

Comment: я подозреваю, что перед вами стоит какая-то глобальная задача, для решения которой вы вабрали sql-event-ы. огласите, пожалуйста, глобальную задачу: вполне возможно, что у неё есть иные, более надёжные и простые решения.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нужно каждый день с a=8 до b=20 часов с интервалом в c=1 час выполнять INSERT инструкцию. Причем, переменные a,b и c хранятся в таблице с одноимёнными полями. Кроме того a,b и c могут измениться в любой момент сторонним php скриптом

Comment: я о глобальной задаче спрашивал. если не можете её озвучить, скажите хотя бы, в какой операционной системе работает демон `mysql`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin win7x64.  Я так понимаю вы мне предложите создать крон?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26300/discussion-between-gar-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: я бы порекомендовал написать скрипт/программу на любом удобном языке программирования, который бы проверял все необходимые условия и, при необходимости, осуществлял какие-то изменения данных, а запускать его средствами операционной системы. в *ms/windows* я практически не разбираюсь, но подозреваю, что там должно быть какое-то встроенное средство для такого запуска.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ну а если извратиться и хотя-бы как-то сделать? не прибегая к оболочке

Comment: если «хотя бы как-то», то я изложил предложение: воспользоваться планировщиком заданий. ввиду того, что *mysql-event-ы*, насколько я вижу из документации, к вашей задаче абсолютно не подходят.